# How do I declare a vector of vector::size_type?

Tags: c++, stl, c++14

I want a vector whose elements are of the type vector::size_type

However, you cannot declare:

```
vector<vector::size_type> aVec;
```

because size_type is part of the template itself, so you have to use the type itself, I need something like:

```
vector<vector<T>::size_type> aVec;
```

but what should the T be?  It's really a circular problem.  :)

If vector had just used size_t as its size type (but not had a special typedef for the size_type which could vary maybe based on the type that the vector is holding), I could just do:

```
vector<size_t> aVec;
```

but, that isn't the case.  I suspect there is a valid reason for it being allowed to vary, but it is making this hard by having it part of the templated vector class instead of outside of it.

Thoughts?

Comment: I do not see a real application of this. Your vector type is defined by what is stored in it. You want to store the sizes of the vector? Of which type?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you're doing something like storing indexes into another vector, do othervector::size_type. If you don't have the template type for vector, it doesn't even make sense trying to get `size_type` for it. Use `size_t`

Comment: `std::size_t` is just an alias for `X::size_type`, isn't it? Looking for a standard quote now.

Comment: Just do `size_t`. However, If you're looking for a canonical "default type" to use as the template parameter, you could use `int`, since it's usually the compiler's "default" type to use.

Comment: @ColinBasnett What is `int` the compiler's "default" for?

Comment: I know that I could do that @David, and that's what I was doing, but what if vector<size_t>::size_type is smaller than size_t?  I can't imagine a scenario where this is the case, but it is possible right? I could watch for that with a static assert I guess.  I just want to be sure there isn't something that I'm not thinking of for a way to do this.

Comment: You say that it is a recursive problem. So are you saying that you want to construct a vector just to store that vector's own size? If you don't want to store the vector type's own size, then why not access the other vector types' type? Or do you want to store the sizes of differently typed vectors? You could try `std::common_type<T1::size_type, T2::size_type>::type` then. But IIRC, the `size_type` is determined only by the allocator. However, don't take my word for it.

Comment: @juanchopanza My mistake, was referring to the old C standard that assumed integer type for any unspecified/unkown type.

Comment: @Mark I didn't mean use vector<size_t>::size_type, I meant just use `size_t`. period.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Using `int` for the size of anything in C has a long history of screwing things up. Just use `size_t` as God intended.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector<>::size_type` is static member type of the type `std::size_t` so you should be safe with `std::vector<std::size_t> vec`

Comment: It's not guaranteed to be `size_t`.

Comment: The standard defines `size_type` as `typedef implementation-defined size_type;`.  We cannot actually know what it is without checking the implementation.  All we know is that it has to be unsigned and size_type can
represent any
non-negative value of
difference_type

Comment: @NathanOliver The standard containers define `size_type` as a typedef to `Allocator::size_type` which for `std::allocator` is defined to be `size_t`. Since there's no user-specified allocator provided, `std::allocator` will be used.

Comment: @Quest Where?  The code block I used in my comment was copied directly from the C++14 standard 23.3.6 in the vector class body.

Comment: @NathanOliver C++03 specified "Table 32: size_type: a type that can represent the size of the largest object in the allocation model." At the time, size_t was the bet practical implementation of those constraints. However, in C++11, it is now defined essentially as: std::make_unsigned<X::difference_type>::type by default. Which in practice, will probably be the same or compatible with size_t
C++14 is on the same track. I can be mistaken but I really don't see any problem in using size_t for this purpose

Comment: @Quest probably but you cannot actually guarantee that *`std::vector<>::size_type` is static member type of the type `std::size_t`*

Comment: @NathanOliver : Yes you can, because every example lobbied here uses `std::vector<T>::size_type`, not `std::vector<T, A>::size_type`, so it will always be `std::allocator` and consequently `size_type` will always be `std::size_t`.

Comment: @ildjarn Where does it say that?  There is nothing in the current standard that says `size_t` will be used.  Even `size_type` for `std::allocator` dosen't specify `size_t`.

Comment: @NathanOliver : [default.allocator] in every standard shows it explicitly. What 'standard' are you referring to? o_O

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes is does. Check [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) page

Comment: @ildjarn I stand correct.  I was looking at [allocator.requirements].  That said `std::vector::size_type` is *size_type can represent any non-negative value of difference_type* and if we look at `difference_type` we have *is identical to the difference type of X::iterator* and then [iterator.basic] has `typedef Distance difference_type;` where `Distance = ptrdiff_t` and then *The type ptrdiff_t is an implementation-defined signed integer type that can hold the difference of two subscripts in an array object, as described in 5.7.* so I fail to see where the allocator comes into play.

Comment: @NathanOliver : To be honest, it's unclear to me what you're trying to prove to whom. It is indeed "implementation-defined", but every implementation I have ever seen uses `typedef typename Alloc::size_type size_type;`. In practice it would be insane not to.

Comment: @ildjarn All I am trying to say is you cannot just blanketly state that `size_type == size_t`.  This answer does so I take issue with that.

Comment: You really can, because you won't find any implementation where it isn't. IMO this answer is useful because it reflects reality, even if it's not up to the pedantry of language-lawyering. :-]

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `vector<vector<int>::size_type> myVector;`? If you never use the type `vector<int>`anywhere else, it doesn't cost anything as template instanciation is somehow lazy. You can use any other type than `int` if you which.

It is very unlikely that `vector<T>::size_type` will be different than `vector<T'>::size_type`.

Comment: "*It is very unlikely that `vector<T>::size_type` will be different than `vector<T'>::size_type`.*" Actually it would be impossible, since both use `std::allocator` which always uses `std::size_t`.

Answer (score 1):

(I am rewritting an answer here, without making any claims about the standard this time.)

You can make your *best guess* for the type (which can be `std::size_t` or `std::vector<void*>::size_type`) and check after the fact.

```
std::vector<std::size_t> Avec;
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(Avec)::size_type, decltype(Avec)::value_type>(), "bad guess");
```

Comment: I also think it is a best solution. It is at least portable =)

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that size_t might be the way to go:

    `using SizeT = std::vector<size_t>::size_type;`
    `std::vector<SizeT> myVec;`

But, I also realized that this was purely a theoretical question for the most part too.  Thanks everyone who commented!  :)