# std::size_t vs. size_type as parameters and function return types

Tags: c++, encapsulation, c++98, size-t, size-type

Suppose I have this code. Which method is better?

```
// Method 1
std::size_t size()
{
  // m_myVector is of type std::vector<MyClass*> in all examples
  return m_myVector.size();
}

// Method 2
std::vector<MyClass*>::size_type size()
{
  // m_myVector is of type std::vector<MyClass*> in all examples
  return m_myVector.size();
}
```

The first way works in 99% of cases, but of course there's the off-chance that the size of the vector isn't of type `std::size_t`. That said, we can just rely on a software analysis tool to tell us that the return type of the size of the vector has changed.

The second way exposes implementation detail of the vector to the caller. Does this break encapsulation? I don't know, you tell me!

Here's another more complex example. Which method is better?

```
void doFoo(const SomeClass& someObject)
{
  // These could be ints or size_types... Feel free to use your imagination
  std::size_t firstCount = someObject.getFirstCount();
  for (std::size_t i = 0U; i < firstCount; ++i)
  {
    foo(firstCount);
  }
}

void doFoo2(const SomeClass& someObject)
{
  // I thought I'd provide another example to help your imagination :)
  std::vector<MyClass*>::size_type secondCount = someObject.getSecondCount();
  for (std::vector<MyClass*>::size_type i = 0U; i < secondCount; ++i)
  {
    foo(secondCount);
  }
}

void doFoo3(const SomeClass& someObject)
{
  // The correct styling would be: NotMyClass*
  // But I really wanted to emphasize this was different from above, so I ALL CAPPED IT
  std::vector<NOTMYCLASS*>::size_type thirdCount = someObject.getThirdCount();
  for (std::vector<NOTMYCLASS*>::size_type i = 0U; i < thirdCount; ++i)
  {
    foo(thirdCount);
  }
}

// Method 1
void foo(std::size_t index)
{
  // m_myVector is of type std::vector<MyClass*> in all examples
  m_myVector.at(index)->doLotsOfStuff();
}

// Method 2
void foo(std::vector<MyClass*>::size_type index)
{
  // m_myVector is of type std::vector<MyClass*> in all examples
  m_myVector.at(index)->doLotsOfStuff();
}
```

Okay this is a lengthy example so I'll explain what's going on. `doFoo()`, `doFoo2()`, and `doFoo3()` all call `foo()` which takes in a `std::size_t` in the first implementation or `std::vector<MyClass*>::size_type` in the second implementation.

`doFoo()` is passing in a `std::size_t` to `foo()`, so the first implementation of `foo()` makes more sense here but then we index a `std::vector<MyClass*>` which is expecting a `std::vector<MyClass*>::size_type`. Not particularly great if `size_type` was not defined to be `std::size_t`.

`doFoo2()` is passing in a `std::vector<MyClass*>::size_type` to `foo()`, so the second implementation of `foo()` works very nicely here. No gripes other than exposing the implementation details of the private vector to the caller. And finally I'd imagine that we would need to [include a separate header for `MyClass`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693665/do-i-really-need-to-return-typesize-type).

`doFoo3()` is passing in a `std::vector<NOTMYCLASS*>::size_type` to `foo()`... And neither implementation of `foo()` expects this because the only vector that `foo()` cares about is the vector which holds elements of type `MyClass*`. Now, as an academic question, is `std::vector<NOTMYCLASS*>::size_type` always the same as `std::vector<MyClass*>::size_type`? I actually don't know the answer to this one, but I've been hearing ['yes' and 'no'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36484539/5849965). And finally, there's that issue of encapsulation once again (if it is an issue).

Anyways, thanks for bearing with me. Thoughts?

Comment: For containers that have a `size_type` defined, use that.  Otherwise, use `size_t`.

Comment: I don't like advertising that there's a `vector` in `SomeClass` unless I have to. This is a reasonable time to go even more abstract and add a `using size_type = <whatever>;` to `SomeClass` so no one knows or cares. Plus you can change the backing type out pretty much whenever you want without the clients having to get involved.

Comment: Let's be honest, in practice `size_type` always ends up being same as `size_type`.

Comment: Why not use `auto`, which works 100% of the time.

Comment: @NathanOliver C++98 :)

Comment: Oh, bummer.  Hopefully one day you can upgrade.  FWIW, you can't really go wrong using `size_t`.  It's guaranteed to be able to hold the size of the largest object, so your vector size should never overflow it.

Comment: Define your own `size_type`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but of course there's the off-chance that the size of the vector isn't of type std::size_t

Such off-chance doesn't practically exist in this case because `std::vector<MyClass*>::size_type` is (indirectly guaranteed and required to be) of type `std::size_t`. Using `std::size_t` is fine in this case, and it doesn't leak unnecessary implementation details.

---

In the case of standard containers, `Container::size_type` is defined based directly on on what allocator is being used. Thus, using `size_type` is typically only necessary when the allocator type - or the container type itself - is templated. In the allocator case, you can use allocator traits instead of the container member type which allows you to keep the container type hidden. If the container type itself is templated, then there is no point in hiding it since only someone who knows the container could have instantiated the template in the first place.

Furthermore, you can hide - or rather obfuscate (in a positive, encapsulating way) - the function declaration by creating a type alias member, just like `std::vector` has a type alias member based on its allocator.

Example:

```
template<class Alloc>
class Foo
{
    // could be hidden with PIMPL if desired
    std::vector<MyClass*, Alloc> m_myVector;

public:
    // Since C++11
    using size_type = typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::size_type;
    // Prior to C++11
    typedef typename Alloc::size_type size_type;
    
    size_type size();
};
```

Comment: Good point about `std::vector<MyClass*>::size_type` being of type `std::size_t `. To add on to the answer, I found this other answer citing the standard: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4849780/5849965

Answer (score 2):

`std::size_t` is a type capable of holding the size of any array, including arrays allocated through allocators.

This means that `std::size_t` will always be able to store the result of `std::vector<T>::size()`, so method 1 will never lead to an overflow and is perfectly readable.

There is no guarantee that `std::vector<T>::size_type` is the same for all `T`, but you would be hard-pressed to find an implementation of `std::vector` where `size_type` is not always `std::size_t`.

Comment: Note that while this is true for vectors it need not be true for other containers. I have a type that virtualizes file contents such that even in 32-bit builds the container's size_type is a 64-bit type (I suppose if I were to port this to a system that did not support files larger than 4gb then this should be changed).

Comment: I believe that `std::vector<T>::size_type` is required to be the same as `std::allocator<T>::size_type`, isn't it?  which is guaranteed to be `std::size_t`. It's only when you deal with `std::vector<T, MyAllocator>` when you have to deal with edge cases.

Comment: @MooingDuck The standard only requires that `size_type` is unsigned and has a larger maximum than `difference_type`. libstdc++ seems to always have it be `size_t`, whereas libc++ and MSVC++'s STL seem to use `std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::size_type`, but either way the size is still guaranteed to fit in a `size_t`